# how to add custom user field in User of admin page of django?

Tags: python, html, django

Will anybody help me? I have tried so much. I have read documentation but not understanding how to add custom user field in User of admin page? Whenever I `makemigrations`, it gives me following error.

**Different pages**

```
#admin.py
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
admin.site.register(UserProfile, UserAdmin)

#models.py
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
class UserProfile(AbstractUser):
    Id_card_number = models.CharField(max_length=15)

#forms.py
class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)._unique = True
    Id_card_number = forms.CharField(max_length=15, required=True)._unique = True
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields  = ['username','email','password1','password2','Id_card_number']
```

**Error whenever I use `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.UserProfile'` in settings.py**

> ERRORS: auth.User.groups: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for
>   'User.groups' clashes with reverse accessor for 'UserProfile.groups'.
>           HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'User.groups' or 'UserProfile.groups'. auth.User.user_permissions:
>   (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'User.user_permissions' clashes
>   with reverse accessor for 'UserProfile.user_permissions'.
>           HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'User.user_permissions' or 'UserProfile.user_permissions'.
>   users.UserProfile.groups: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for
>   'UserProfile.groups' clashes with reverse accessor for 'User.groups'.
>           HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'UserProfile.groups' or 'User.groups'.
>   users.UserProfile.user_permissions: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for
>   'UserProfile.user_permissions' clashes with reverse accessor for
>   'User.user_permissions'.
>           HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'UserProfile.user_permissions' or 'User.user_permissions'.

**Error whenever I don't use `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.UserProfile'` in settings.py**

> ERRORS: users.Profile.user: (fields.E301) Field defines a relation
>   with the model  'auth.User', which has been swapped out.    HINT:
>   Update the relation to point at 'settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL'.

Comment: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html#abstractbaseuser

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried importing `from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser`?

Your User will then inherit from AbstractBaseUser:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser
class UserProfile(AbstracBasetUser):
    Id_card_number = models.CharField(max_length=15)
```

Comment: Yes I tried but it is giving me ```django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unknown field(s) (username, email) specified for UserProfile```

Comment: Well you are using `fields  = ['username','email','password1','password2','Id_card_number']` but your Model has no username nor email so the error makes sense. The method is not finding these fields in your UserProfile model.

Comment: I used ```{{form|crispy}}``` in register.html and I gave additional email and Id_card_number.

Answer (score 0):

model.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class User(AbstractUser):
    password1 = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    password2 = models.CharField(max_length=250)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'caccounts_user'
        verbose_name = 'User'
```

You can over write with the help of above code. place the above code and `make migation` then `migarte`

Comment: I have applied but it is still not working. I just asked a simple question. How could I add Id_card_number field in User admin page? I have become tired now but nobody is answering.

Answer (score 0):

I did it this way and is working perfectly fine:

```py
#models.py
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    # add additional fields in here

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

```py
#forms.py
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, UserChangeForm
from .models import CustomUser

class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):

    class Meta(UserCreationForm):
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ('username', 'email')

class CustomUserChangeForm(UserChangeForm):

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ('username', 'email')
```

```py
#admin.py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin

from .forms import CustomUserCreationForm, CustomUserChangeForm
from .models import CustomUser

class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    add_form = CustomUserCreationForm
    form = CustomUserChangeForm
    model = CustomUser
    list_display = ['email', 'username',]

admin.site.register(CustomUser, CustomUserAdmin)
```

And in settings:

```py
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.CustomUser'
```

Comment: I have applied but it is still not working. I just asked a simple question. How could I add Id_card_number field in User admin page? I have become tired now but nobody is answering.

Comment: Do you want to add Id_card_number field to show on the login page of django-admin?